# Getting is not a function error for jquery based libraries Rails 6 Webpack

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, webpack

I have tried multiple ways to get JQuery to initialize for libraries like datetimepicker() owlcarousel() and various other jquery based components. I have no issue with using jquery for semantic-ui -- which is weird. But, JQuery does not work for anything else that I use in my project. I'm currently running Rails 6/ruby 2.6.3. I will list out the error/webpack config that I have. **How do I setup jQuery to work globally?**

**ERROR**

```
jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).owlCarousel is not a function TypeError: $(...).owlCarousel is not a function
```

**Application.js**

```
window.jQuery = $;
window.$ = $;
window.moment = moment;
window.ActiveStorageDragAndDrop = ActiveStorageDragAndDrop;


import {} from 'jquery-ujs'
import "./semantic.min"
import "cocoon";
import "./data-confirm-modal-semantic-ui"
import "./jquery.maskMoney"
import "./datepicker.min"
import "./datepicker.en"
import "./trix"
import "./tablesort"
import "./jquery.tagsinput-revisited"
import "@client-side-validations/simple-form"
import * as ActiveStorageDragAndDrop from "active_storage_drag_and_drop"
import moment from 'moment'
import "./jquery.daterangepicker.min"
import "owl.carousel";

require('@client-side-validations/client-side-validations');
require("chartkick");
require("chart.js");
require("@rails/activestorage").start();
require("channels");
require('jquery');

ActiveStorageDragAndDrop.start();
```

**environment.js**

```
 const {environment} = require('@rails/webpacker');
    const webpack = require('webpack');

    environment.plugins.prepend('Provide',
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: 'jquery/src/jquery',
            jquery: 'jquery/src/jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery/src/jquery', 'window.jQuery': 'jquery/src/jquery',
            moment: 'moment'
        })
    );

    module.exports = environment;
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "test_app_sys",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@client-side-validations/client-side-validations": "^0.1.1",
    "@client-side-validations/simple-form": "^0.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.12.1",
    "@rails/actioncable": "^6.0.0-alpha",
    "@rails/activestorage": "^6.0.0-alpha",
    "@rails/webpacker": "^4.0.7",
    "@yaireo/tagify": "yaireo/tagify",
    "active_storage_drag_and_drop": "^0.3.4",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.3",
    "chartkick": "^3.2.0",
    "cocoon": "github:nathanvda/cocoon#c24ba53",
    "flow-webpack-plugin": "^1.2.0",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "jquery-ujs": "latest",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "owl.carousel": "^2.3.4",
    "stimulus": "^1.1.1"
  },
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.9.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add to your app/javascript/packs/application.js:

```
// export jquery to global
var jQuery = require('jquery')
// include jQuery in global and window scope (so you can access it globally)
// in your web browser, when you type $('.div'), it is actually refering to global.$('.div')
global.$ = global.jQuery = jQuery;
window.$ = window.jQuery = jQuery;
```

I get this way to enable jQuery for other puglins on Rails 6 with Webpacker from here: https://rubyyagi.com/how-to-integrate-html-bootstrap-theme-into-rails-6/#debugging-javascript-issues

Comment: @MbaUchenna Do you have the tag  `<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>` on app/views/layouts/application.html.erb?